# SQL: Obtain X, Y attributes for the greatest number of ID's (items sold)

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have 2 tables, one containing tickets and the other routes. I want to produce 2 attributes, flight_DATE and route_CODE, for the greatest numbers of tickets sold. Since there is no attribute that stores the number of tickets sold I have to perform a query finding the max() on the number of count(ticket_ID), as each ticket_ID represents a ticket sold... right? I have no actual database to try this out so that's my query:

```
SELECT routes.ROUTE_CODE , tickets.FLIGHT_DATE
    FROM routes JOIN tickets ON routes.ROUTE_CODE = tickets.ROUTE_CODE
WHERE count(ticket.TICKET_ID)  = (
            SELECT max(count(ticket.TICKET_ID)
            )
```

I am not so confident with SQL so is this even correct??? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind your query is correct, but you wrote the `max` calculation without a level, so you will get the count of all the tickets sold.

You also cannot put in your `where` clause a condition on an aggregated column (as you did with count(`ticket.TICKET_ID`); that kind of condition goes to the `having` clause.

This one should do what you need

```
SELECT  ROUTE_CODE, FLIGHT_DATE
JOIN    tickets
GROUP BY ROUTE_CODE , FLIGHT_DATE
HAVING  count(tickets.TICKET_ID) = ( /*filter the row with count = max count */
          SELECT  max(CNT) /* get the max of the counts */
          FROM    (
                    SELECT  count(TICKET_ID) as CNT /* get the counts at desired levels */
                    FROM    tickets
                    GROUP BY FLIGHT_DATE, ROUTE_CODE
                  )
        )
```

I removed the `join` with `routes` table because the only column you were using (`ROUTE_CODE`) is available on the `tickets` table too, but that may be useful if you want to select more data from that table and definitely was not an error.

BTW, if you don't have a database available for testing, you can try your queries on sites like [rextester](http://rextester.com/)